# How do i integrate Two branch.io deep link with single app

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

We have 2 servers, let's says ABC and XYZ. Both have different deep link environment 
Deeplink from ABC is app.ABC.com
Deeplink from XYZ is app.XYZ.com

It should target ABC server if a deep link from that server and same for XYZ. 
we set up ABC in plist, we can add only one BranchKey at a time in plist. so when we hit deep link for other server links it shows it is a non-branch link.

is any possibility to achieve 2 host server for 2 different deep links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found way,

each branch deep link has 2 domain

1. Custom link domain
2. Alternate Link Domain

We can use `Alternate Link Domain` for achieving above case.not sure this is a proper way but we can achieve the result we want with this.